# Initializing EBS Volume in EC2 Windows Instance using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a custom windows AMI and whenever i create a new Instance using it I want to Initialize an additional drive automatically depending on the requirements. I am trying to do this using Terraform.

I am getting the drive but had to manually initialize it.

create and ec2 instance and attach volume.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-098792953bbd38e18"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs-volume-1" {
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
    size = 160
    type = "st1"
    tags {
        Name = "more volume"
    }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs-volume-1-attachment" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdf"
  volume_id = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-1.id}"
   instance_id = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your existing Terraform code? What steps are you having to perform to manually initialise the additional EBS volume?

Comment: I have not got that part. I am just able to attach the volume but not able to initialize.  below i am creating a volume and attaching it. This is generic step.
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "Drive" {
  availability_zone = "ap-south-1b"
  size              = 8
  tags = {
    Name = "Hello"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name  = "xvdj"
  volume_id    = "${aws_ebs_volume.Drive.id}"
  instance_id  = "${aws_instance.windows.id}"
  skip_destroy = true
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["tags"]
  }
}

Comment: You should edit your question to include any requested changes, particularly code as this allows you to nicely format it in a code block so that people can read it.

Comment: I tried that. Its not allowing to submit for some wierd reason saying format is wrong.

Comment: I am able to add the sample code i am using to create an instance and attach volume. But not sure how to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on Ubuntu 18 so you will have to modify but putting this here because this is non-obvious imo.

```
### instance.tf

resource "aws_instance" "main" {
  user_data = data.local_file.user_data
  # ...
}
```

```
### user_data.sh

DEVICE="/dev/xvdf"

# Get device id
DEVICE_FS=`sudo lsblk -o UUID -d ${DEVICE} -n`

# Create a file system on the volume if one does not already exist
 if [ "`echo -n $DEVICE_FS`" == "" ] ; then
         mkfs.ext4 ${DEVICE}
 fi

# Create a mount point directory
 sudo mkdir /data

# Backup fstab
 sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig

# Setup auto mount on reboot
 echo "UUID=${DEVICE_FS} /data xfs defaults,nofail 0 2" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab

# Unmount
 sudo umount /data

# Mount and exit on error
 sudo mount -a
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
    echo "Mounted"
 else
    exit 1
 fi
```